# Bash script cannot access error while reading file

Tags: bash, shell

I have written a small program to get the list of all files in a directory and concatenating them to a single string variable. Here's the code

```
#!/bin/bash
dir ="/home/user/myfolder/abc"
res=" "

for f in $( ls $dir  ); do
    res="$res $f"
done

echo $res
```

However I am getting the following error

```
dir: cannot access =/home/user/myfolder/abc: No such file or directory
```

I have set all the required permissions, whats the solution?

Comment: Oh! thats because I havent found answers which can solve my problems. I will accept your answer in 11 mins..Thanks to SO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the space between the assignment:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir ="/home/user/myfolder/abc"
```

Do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="/home/user/myfolder/abc"
```

Each language has its own syntax, and bash scripting requires no spaces between `left_value=right_value` during assignments; as you see, it's simply a matter of syntax.

Comment: This works! But its strange!! Whats with the assignment and the spaces??

Answer (score 3):

likely you need:

```
dir=/home/user/myfolder/abc
```

rather than

```
dir ="/home/user/myfolder/abc"
```

The extra space after **dir** makes it the command "dir", which is usually aliased to **ls**.